# Compare two columns in excel and remove duplicates

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2016

I have this two columns of names:

```
Column 1         Column 2

A                  B
B                  D
C                  E
D
E
```

I need to compare the two columns and have in output the values that are in Column 1 but not in Column 2, so the output must be:

```
Column 3

A
C
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=0,A1,"")
```

and copy down.

[image]

The blanks can also be removed, if necessary.

Comment: Dont you mean COUNTIF(B:B,A1)=1 instead of 0?

Comment: @bub **0** means it is missing from column **B** and should therefore appear in column **C**